# Error when pasting slide: The specified data type is unavailable

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, powerpoint

I am getting following error while pasting a slide in PowerPoint in the following line:

```
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial ppPasteOLEObject, msoFalse
```

> Run-time error -2147188160 (80048240):View (unknown member) : Invalid request. The specified data type is Unavailable

I have run this code multiple times and it was running fine before.

Also, once the object/chart is copying; I am switching to PowerPoint to see if I can paste.
I can paste with all the options (As picture, As Embedded Image, etc.).

Here is the full code till I am getting error as it was not coming in comment section

Here is the code : Till the line where I get error

```
 Sub export_to_ppt()
 Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 'Keep the Importing master sheet address here:
  Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("d:\Documents and   Settings \Export to   ppt.xlsm")

'Keep all the worksheets which you want to import from here:
Path = "D:\Office Documents\2013\ Latest Xcel\" 
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsm")
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
Dim sht As Workbooks

 Set Sheet = Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Issues Concern")
 Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 Set Sheet = Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Key Initiatives Update")
 Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 Set Sheet = Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Solution Update")
 Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 Set Sheet = Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Overall Practice Status")
 Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 Set Sheet = Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Practice Financials")
 Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 Workbooks(Filename).Close
 Filename = Dir()
 Loop
Dim PPApp           As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres          As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide         As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim SlideCount      As Integer
Dim shptbl          As Table
Dim oShape          As PowerPoint.Shape

Dim SelectRange As Range
Dim SelectCell As Range


 Set PPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
 PPApp.Visible = msoTrue
'opening an existing presentation
 Filename = "D:\Office Documents\Presentation1.pptx"
 Set PPPres = PPApp.Presentations.Open(Filename) 
 Dim s As String
 Dim i As Integer
 i = 2
  Line3:
MsgBox (ActiveSheet.Name)

If ActiveSheet.Name Like ("*Solution Update*") Then
GoTo Line1
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name Like ("*Key Initatives Update*") Then
GoTo Line4
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name Like ("*Issues Concern*") Then
GoTo Line13

End If



Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(SlideCount + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)

PPSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Practice Financials - " &  Sheets(i).Range("AH1").Value & "  "

'PPSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Sheets(1).Range("B1").Value

'format header
With PPSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Characters
    .Font.Size = 24
    .Font.Name = "Arial Heading"
    '.Font.Color = vbBlue
End With



Range("A1:K7").Select

Selection.Copy
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide PPSlide.SlideIndex ' activate the slide no
'PPApp.Activate
 PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial ppPasteOLEObject, msoFalse ' paste using pastespecial method
 'PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
 'PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial (ppPasteMetafilePicture)
```

Comment: Where are you running this code from?

Comment: Also what happens when you replace `ppPasteOLEObject` with `ppPasteEnhancedMetafile`

Comment: This code is in an Excel and it is trying to copy the shape from an Excel to a ppt.. I have tried all paste options but still getting the same error...

Comment: There could be two reason why code might be failing. `1` Powerpoint is loosing focus. Add `PPApp.Activate` before you paste. `2` Or the data type might be `ppPasteEnhancedMetafile` instead of `ppPasteOLEObject`.

Comment: BTW I am not in favor of using `Activate/ActiveWindow` etc... I  might as well declare my objects for powerpoint. Say, declare an object for a slide and then use that object to paste. This way even if powerpoint looses focus, the paste will go on smoothly...

Comment: I have tried both the options ; still the same error is coming...anyways thanks for your help ...

Comment: what if you just use `.Paste` ?

Comment: Can you share the code where you are copying the object?

Comment: .Paste is returning the following error :View (unknown member): Invalid request, Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here. But if i go to ppt and do paste ; it has data to be pasted...

Comment: I thought that you were copying a slide but then I realized you were copying a shape. Try using `ppPasteShape` or refer to this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745532.aspx

Comment: Update the code in the question above please.

Comment: You are copying a range? `Range("A1:K7").Select

Selection.Copy` Then you might want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851609/copy-from-excel-to-powerpoint-error

Comment: Also if you are replying to me then add "@" and then my name so that I can get an alert :) For example @Myra

Comment: @SiddharthRout: I am still getting the same error .even after introducing Wait and Do events :(

Comment: Did you try doing `PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial` instead of `PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: In that case following error is coming :Shapes (unknown member) : Invalid request, Clipboard is empty or
contains data which may not be pasted here.

Comment: I just tested it and `pp.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial ppPasteOLEObject, msoFalse` works. Is it possible for me to see your Excel file?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Thanks Siddharth for your help; however that's my office document and wont be able to share..really regret..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comments above, this works for me. Let's say your `sheet1` looks like this

[image]

Paste this code in a module.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim PPApp           As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPPres          As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPSlide         As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim SlideCount      As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Dim Filename As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:K7")

    Set PPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    PPApp.Visible = msoTrue
    'opening an existing presentation
    Filename = "C:\Presentation1.pptx"
    Set PPPres = PPApp.Presentations.Open(Filename)

    SlideCount = PPPres.Slides.count

    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(SlideCount + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)

    With PPSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = "Practice Financials - " & _
                ws.Range("AH1").Value & "  "

        With .Characters.Font
            .Size = 24
            .Name = "Arial Heading"
        End With
    End With

    rng.Copy
    DoEvents

    PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse
End Sub
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem and it happened as I was trying to export from Excel to PowerPoint without the PowerPoint reference, using it as object. The tricky thing was that sometimes it worked, other times it won´t. So after some testing I found out that it depends on the state of the PowerPoint View, if it is showing Thumbnails or a normal Slide view.

To fix it, set the ViewType as normal before pasting.

```
PPAP.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal
```

or

```
PPAP.ActiveWindow.ViewType = 9
```

`PPAP` stands for  power point application object.