# Occasionally running into runtime error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I created a macro to copy cells from my current excel workbook into a powerpoint presentation. The macro works, but occasionally I will get a

> runtime error 1004: CopyPicture method of Range class failed.

on line:

`ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("A1:O" & lastRow).CopyPicture Format:=xlPicture`

I will also occasionally get

> runtime error -2147188160 (80048240): Shapes (unknown member): invalid request. Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here.

on line:

`aSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select`

What's strange is that the errors occur at different places. For example, sometimes an error will occur on the 5th slide, then if I run it again, it will process the 5th slide just fine, but then run into an error again on the 10th slide.

I tried using error handling, but everything I tried ended up freezing the program.

```
Sub CreateSlides()

    Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim aSlide As Slide
    Dim path As String

    path = "C:Users\Me\Documents\WorksheetSlides.pptx"

    Set PPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set PPFile = PPApp.Presentations.Open(path)

    For Each aSlide In PPFile.Slides
        i = aSlide.SlideNumber + 1

        aSlide.Select

        If i > ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count Then Exit For

        lastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("A1:O" & lastRow).CopyPicture Format:=xlPicture
        aSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: For starters, `aSlide.Shapes.Paste` and the `.Select` should not be chained like that.  If you're having timing issues with the Office clipboard you're going to need to deal with the between those 2 calls.  That said, you probably need a short (couple ms) delay after the Copy and before the Paste.

Comment: Add `DoEvents` after the line `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("A1:O" & lastRow).CopyPicture Format:=xlPicture`

Answer (score 1):

This is a notorious issue when pasting from Excel to PowerPoint - the solution is to give the clipboard some breather time by adding a short break inbetween the copy/paste. Here is an example where we wait 2 seconds (which should be long enough):

```
Sub CreateSlides()

    Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim aSlide As Slide
    Dim path As String

    path = "C:Users\Me\Documents\WorksheetSlides.pptx"

    Set PPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set PPFile = PPApp.Presentations.Open(path)

    For Each aSlide In PPFile.Slides
        i = aSlide.SlideNumber + 1

        aSlide.Select

        If i > ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count Then Exit For

        lastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("A1:O" & lastRow).CopyPicture Format:=xlPicture

        Wait

        aSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
    Next

End Sub
Sub Wait()

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")

End Sub
```

Comment: Hardcoding 2 seconds is a bad idea. There is no guarantee that the content will be placed in the clipboard in 2 seconds :) What if the application is busy doing something else? Best to add `DoEvents` and let the application decide the time it needs :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout This is true- my answer is completely subjective here. I’m only answering with what has worked best for me, having tried using DoEvents as well, and I’ve been generating power points from Excel for a while now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851609/copy-from-excel-to-powerpoint-error

Comment: @SiddharthRout What is `Timer` in your second example there?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/timer-function